# Create login and user for Entity Framework with limited permissions

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, crud

I dont want to give sa or windows auth account to Entity Framework. What i want is a limited login and user for CRUD operations and whatever Entity Framework needs else. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my snippet.

```
USE [master];
GO
CREATE LOGIN [yourUser] 
WITH PASSWORD='yourPassword';
GO
USE [yourDB]
GO
CREATE USER [yourUser] 
FROM LOGIN [yourUser] 
WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=yourShema; 
GO
ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [yourUser]; 
GO
ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER [yourUser];
GO
```

Result:

[image: result]